# Merge files into xlsx and then reconstruct the dir

Tags: python, excel, file, binary, openpyxl

I have many files ('*.pl-pl'). My script has to find each of this files and merge them into one `xlsx` file using `openpyxl`.

Now, I want to rebuild those files, I want rebuild the same files as originals.

But there is a problem after writing:

(content variable contains content of one file (read from one excel cell))

```
with open(path,'w') as f:
    f.write(content.encode('utf-8'))
```

So now, I check, whether original files are the same as new files. Text in those files seems to be the same but there are little differencies in size. When I use WinDiff application to check them, it finds some touples which are different but it says that they are `different in blanks only`.

Could you give me an advice how to rebuild those files to be the same as before? 
Or is this way correct?

Note: I try to rebuild them to be sure that there will be the same encoding etc. because the merged excel file will be used to translation and then translated files has to be rebuilt instead of originals.

**Here is the code - it checks directory and prints all file names and contents into the one temporary file. Then, it creates an excel file - 1st. column is path (to be able reconstruct dir) and 2nd column contains content of the file, where new lines has been switched to '*=*'**

```
def print_to_file():
    import os
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("OriginalDir"):
        for file in files:
            text = []
            if file.endswith(".pl-pl"):
                abs_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                with open(abs_path) as f:
                    for line in f:
                        text.append(line.strip('\n'))
            mLib.printToFile('files.mdoc', abs_path + '::' + '*=*'.join(text)) #'*=*' represents '\n'


def write_it():
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    import xlsxwriter
    file = 'files.mdoc'
    workbook = Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]
    worksheet.title = "Translate"
    i = 0

    with open(file) as f:
        classes = set()
        for line in f:
            i += 1

            splitted = line.strip('\n').split('::')
            name = splitted[0]
            text = splitted[1].split('*=*')
            text = [x.encode('string-escape') for x in text]
            worksheet.cell('B{}'.format(i)).style.alignment.wrap_text = True
            worksheet.cell('B{}'.format(i)).value = splitted[1]
            worksheet.cell('A{}'.format(i)).value = splitted[0]
    workbook.save('wrap_text1.xlsx')
import openpyxl

def rebuild():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('wrap_text1.xlsx')
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    row_count = ws.get_highest_row()
    for i in xrange(1, row_count + 1):
        dir_file = ws.cell('A{}'.format(i)).value
        content = ws.cell('B{}'.format(i)).value
        remake(dir_file, content)


import os
def remake(path, content):

    content = re.sub('\*=\*', '\n', content)
    result = ''
    splt = path.split('\\')
    file = splt[-1]
    for dir in splt[:-1]:
        result += dir + '/'
        # print result
        if not os.path.isdir(result):
            # print result
            os.mkdir(result)
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(content.encode('utf-8'))


# print_to_file() # print to temp file - paths and contents separated by '::'
# write_it() # write it into the excel file
# rebuilt() # reconstruct directory
```

Comment: Differences in whitespace could simply be down to line-endings.

Some of this code looks excessively complex, it's certainly not using the openpyxl API as it should. If I understand the question correctly, you should concentrate on writing a function to recreate the files and write tests for that.